# How can extract float and numeric values using regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have string

```
MATERIAL :    51670 TUD1 =  .1200  m    TLD1 =  .0750  m TUD2 =  .0620  m    TLD2 =  .0380  m TUDH =  .0680  m    TLDH = .0420  m
```

I only want to extract `[51670, .1200, .0750, .0620, .0380, .0680, .0420]`

I have tried `re.findall("[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", lines)` but it returns `[' 51670', '1', '.1200', '1', '.0750', '2', '.0620', '2', '.0380', '.0680', '.0420']` which is not what I want. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
(?<!\w)[-+]?\d*\.?\d+(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TP6KgD/2)

Here, the pattern matches

- `(?<!\w)` - a location in the string that is not immediately preceded with a word char (letter, digit or `_`). To allow `_`, replace `(?<!\w)` with `(?<![^\W_])`
- `[-+]?`  - an optional `-` or `+`
- `\d*\.?\d+` - 0+ digits, an optinal dot and 1+ digits
- `(?!\d)` - no digit allowed immediately to the right of the current location.

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZZYLhd):

```
import re
text = "MATERIAL :    51670 TUD1 =  .1200  m    TLD1 =  .0750  m TUD2 =  .0620  m    TLD2 =  .0380  m TUDH =  .0680  m    TLDH = .0420  m"
print( re.findall(r'(?<!\w)[-+]?\d*\.?\d+(?!\d)', text) )
# => ['51670', '.1200', '.0750', '.0620', '.0380', '.0680', '.0420']
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
import re
lines = 'MATERIAL :    51670 TUD1 =  .1200  m    TLD1 =  .0750  m TUD2 =  .0620  m    TLD2 =  .0380  m TUDH =  .0680  m    TLDH = .0420  m'
numbers = re.findall(r"\s(\.?\d+)\s",lines)
print(numbers)
```

Output:

```
['51670', '.1200', '.0750', '.0620', '.0380', '.0680', '.0420']
```

I simply look for 0 or 1 `.` (`\.?`) followed by 1 or more digits (`\d+`), which are between whitespaces (`\s`). I put `\s`es outside group so they will not appear in `numbers`. Note that above code will find all numbers from your example, but not numbers like `12.34` - to find them too use `r"\s(\d+\.?\d+)\s"`. Note that `.` needs to be escaped as character with special meaning.